# Indexing a Dictionary with a Span

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a Dictionary indexed with a string array:

```
new Dictionary<string[], T>(new CustomComparer())
```

I would like to use a Span to index into the dictionary without copying it to an array first.

Is there a way to achieve this? I can't do

```
new Dictionary<Span<string>, T>(new CustomComparer())
```

Neither can I use IReadonlyCollection as Span does not implement any interfaces.

Comment: You want to index a dictionary using a string array? What are you trying to do? If the key length is fixed, it might be a better idea to use a tuple.

Comment: How do you access the elements with a list of string as key?

Comment: @Jawad By the means of the `CustomComparer`?..

Comment: Have `Dictionary<IEnumerable<string>, T>` instead, and `CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>`?

Comment: @GSerg, I tried that but I can't pass a Span to an indexer that expects an IEnumerable<string> because Span does not implement any interfaces.

Comment: @Luaan, no, the key length is not fixed.

Comment: @SergeySlepov I mean, use `IEnumerable` instead of span. As I understand, you wanted to avoid copying the strings into an array, which you can avoid with the `IEnumerable`. Then again, as strings are immutable, copying them is always copying the pointers, so there's not much to gain in the first place.

Comment: @GSerg, the key is part of a Queue in my case and currently I copy the required range out of the queue into an array: dictionary[queue.Take(n).ToArray()]. I would like to avoid the copying and the allocation as it is a fairly tight loop.

Comment: Please update your question. What is the type of `queue`? Using LINQ (e.g. `Take(n)` is not ideal for highly performant code. How would you extract from `queue` into a `Span`?

Comment: `Span` can't be stored on the heap; `Memory` is the type for that. `Memory` avoids allocation but the trade-off from `Span` is each access requires a second addition. (Or in your case, `ReadOnlyMemory<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to use `System.Collections.Generic` with `Span`. Dictionary and other data structures from `System.Collections.Generic` are allocated on the *heap*, while `Span` is a `ref` struct and is allocated on the *stack*. The compiler won't allow it.

As an alternative, you can write your own stack-based dictionary/hash map implementation, using `Span<string>` for keys.

Comment: Not true for `List<T>`! Use can use `CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list)` to create a `Span<T>` of that list